# How to access a generic list and assign the object of generic list to another object

Tags: c#, list, generics

In my project I am having a generic list in which I will be receiving the input value. But since it is generic I am not able to iterate and get the value of the inner List.

```
class Input
{

 List<Class1<Class2>> obj;
}

class Class1<T>
{
  List<T> innerObj;
}

class Class2
{
  int ID;
  string value;
}
```

Since the Class1 is generic , anything can be passed in place of T. But at a given instance, how can I access the properties of Class2 when it is passed through Class1 object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looping though InputObj.Obj property

```
var inputObj = new Input()//assuming you have populated obj

foreach(var class1Obj in inputObj.obj)
{
  foreach(var class2Obj in class1Obj.innerObj)
  { 
    // here you have the list of class 2 objects
  }
}
```

You have to loop through the corresponding property list.